# Custom Format on Masked TextBox

Tags: c#

Is it possible with a Masked Textbox to have a format like:

```
£*0.00
```

Where the *0 can be any amount of numeric digits?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/.
It has a MaskedTextBox http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox that handle currencies.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with MaskedTextBox as the Mask property defines patterns of fixed length (thus something like '0.00' would be at most '9.99'). You could try to use the '9/#' chars for optional digits, but not likely to help you a lot there.

Maybe you want to take a look at NumericUpDown, which however doesn't let you put a format (in this case the pound sign).

Other choices would be: a) to do the text handling yourself, which of course would involve more than a pair of lines, or b) use a UserControl to bundle a label/textbox (for the pound char) + a NumericUpDown control.